# Google Drive API V3 - Login required 401 Error

Tags: laravel, oauth, google-drive-api

I was trying to connect my web app written in Laravel to connect with google drive.I use Flysystem Adapter. Unfortunately i am stuck with the following error. It is currently running in my local environment.While creating oAuth credentials i chose Desktop App. it is showing 401 error? I have added client id, client secret , refersh token and folder id.

```
    Google_Service_Exception
    { "error": { "errors": [ { "domain": "global", "reason": "required", "message": "Login Required", 
    "locationType": "header", "location": "Authorization" } ], "code": 401, "message": "Login 
    Required" } }
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the cache. I cleared and optimized the cache and everything is working !

Comment: i 've tried with pa optimize:clear , still doesnt work....